# Manipulating DisplayMember before it is displayed

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datasource

Let's say I am using databinding like this:

```
List<Entity> Entities = <some data>

entityBinding.DataSource = Entities;
lstEntities.DisplayMember = "Description";
```

which works fine.  However, I want to manipulate the string coming back as the Entity's "Description".  How can I call a function on DisplayMember?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call a function on that field - but you could create a new property on your entity called `MyDescription` which does to `Description` whatever it is you want to do, and then use that new property as your `DisplayMember`